# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable. What does it mean?

Tags: python, typeerror

this is my code but when i try to run it is says: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable.
Why is that? Can anyone help me?

```
import numpy

eps = 0.0102985
sig = 3.4
```

for r in numpy.arange(3, 6.05, 0.05):

```
  V = 4*eps((sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6)
  print('{} \n {}'.format(r, V))
```

Comment: you have `eps = 0.0102985`, which is `float`. Then you have `eps(...)`, i.e. you tray to **call** the number (as you calll a function), but you cannot call number, hence you are getting `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Comment: You should try `V = 4*eps*((sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6)`

Comment: While in the language of mathematics, multiplication does not require a strict symbol `*`, in Python and most other languages, it *is* required

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a multiplication sign in this line:

`V = 4*eps((sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6)`

Try:

`V = 4*eps*((sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6)`

Without the multiplication sign python thinks you're trying to call `eps` as a function like `eps()` which leads to the `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Comment: To continue the answer, functions and classes are callables, example, `str(x)`. We cant use mathematical shortcuts like `a(b+c)` as the compiler parses `a`  as a callable, hence you have to use the full expression `a*(b+c)`

Answer (score 0):

An operator is missing between eps and the bracket

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot a `*` here:

```py
V = 4*eps((sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6)
```

You are calling eps as if it is a function and not a float.
It should be

```py
V = 4*eps*((sig/r)**12 - (sig/r)**6)
```